# jQuery get data from db after button clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I was creating a like button and automatically increasing value and getting current value on db.

The update value worked, but the value didn't update automatically after the button was clicked (it's updated after the page has refreshed).

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#like').on('click', function(e){
        var id = '{{$news->id}}';
        $.get('{{ url('home/like')}}/'+id, function(data){
            console.log(id);
            console.log(data);
            $('#like_data').empty();
            $.each(data, function(index, element){
                $('#like_data').append('<p>'+element.like+'</p>');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<form method="GET">
    <div id="sample-table-3">
        <a id="like"><img src="/images/likes1.png" title="likes"></a>
    </div>
</form>

<div id="like_data">
    <p>{{$news->like}}</p>
</div>
```

I'm getting an error like this:

> GET http://localhost:8080/view/like/4 500 (Internal Server Error)
>
> XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:8080/view/like/4".

---Edit: added controller and routes---

```
//Controller    
public function like($id){
    $news = News::find($id);

    $news->like += 1;
    $news->save();

    return view('home.view')->with('news', $news);
}

//Laravel Route 
Route::get('/home/like/{id}', 'HomeController@like');
```

Comment: A 500 error means the problem is with your server side code, not your JS. To be able to help you, we need to see that code.

Comment: edit your question with your server side script... as the error is internal server error

Comment: Check the response tab in your web debugger tool. Might show you the server side error.

Comment: hi :) i was edited my question to add controller and routes on laravel

Comment: You're defining your route as /home/like/{id} but you make the request to /view/like/{id}